# rails 3.2 searching action. how to pass results to another action

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, activerecord

I should create a search page in which i have to save in an Array all the results of the searching. I had two problems:

1) I used the following statement:

```
Company.joins(:references).where(sql_string)
```

that returns an `ActiveRecord:Relation` and it's not good for me cause i have to display these results in the index action , in which i use an `each` statement. So , to overcame this problem i used the `to_a`.
I checked the `.class` of my variable and with the `to_a` it passed from `ActiveRecord:Relation` to `Array`. So , it seems that this solve the problem.

```
Company.joins(:references).where(sql_string).to_a
```

2) Now, i have to pass this variable (`Array`) into my `index` action.
I executed the search in the action called `search`:

```
def search
   ...
   @companies = Company.joins(:references).where(sql_string).to_a
end
```

Now, i want to pass this to `index`:

```
def index
  @companies ||= Company.all
end
```

I used   `@companies ||= Company.all` cause i think that the  `@companies` is and istance variable and it should be available in all the actions of the class. Isn't it? By the way, it doesn't workl. I mean , the results are not shared through the two methods.
Also , in the `search` action i don't know how to call `index` action. I used the `redirect_to` but this bring me to another problem.

```
def search
   ...
   @companies = Company.joins(:references).where(sql_string).to_a
   redirect_to companies_index_path
end
```

The second time i call the search action it brings me into the index action.As i insered the searching value. At really he still had the past searching in memory, and i don't want this behavior.
So , in other words, i want to:

1. **passing @companies searching result to index action.**
2. **avoid the loop between `search-index`. So in every new request resets
       the old searching.**
3. **i want to know if it's correct the casting with the `to_a` to bring
       an `ActiveRecord:Relation` to `Array`.**

Thank You.

**EDIT:**

```
    def search

    stringa_sql = ""
    ragione_sociale = ""
    riferimento = ""
    note = ""
    min_date = ""
    max_date = ""
    company_type = ""
    sector = ""
    country = ""
    certification = ""
    contact = ""
    state = ""
    manage = ""
    consultation = ""
    formation = ""
    software = ""

        if params[:ragione_sociale]

            ragione_sociale = params[:ragione_sociale]
          stringa_sql = "ragione_sociale like "+"'%"+ragione_sociale+"%'"

        end



        if params[:riferimento]

            riferimento = params[:riferimento]
        stringa_sql += " AND nome like "+"'%"+riferimento+"%'"
        end

        if params[:note]

            note = params[:note]
        stringa_sql += " AND note like "+"'%"+note+"%'"

        end



        if params[:min_date] && params[:min_date]!= ""

            if params[:max_date] && params[:max_date]!= ""

                min_date = params[:min_date]

                max_date = params[:max_date]
        stringa_sql += " AND richiamare >="+min_date+" AND richiamare <="+max_date

            end     

        end



        if params[:company_type] #se inviamo la richesta senza scrivere params[:category] viene passato vuoto

            if params[:company_type][:id] != ""

                company_type = params[:company_type][:id]
          stringa_sql += " AND id_forma_giuridica = "+company_type

            end

        end     



        if params[:sector] 

            if params[:sector][:id] != ""

                sector = params[:sector][:id]
          stringa_sql += " AND id_settore = "+sector

            end

        end



        if params[:country] 

            if params[:country][:id] != ""

                country = params[:country][:id]
            stringa_sql += " AND id_provincia = "+country

            end

        end



        if params[:certification] 

            if params[:certification][:id] != ""

                certification = params[:certification][:id]
              stringa_sql += " AND id_certificazione = "+certification

            end

        end     



        if params[:contact] 

            if params[:contact][:id] != ""

                contact = params[:contact][:id]
              stringa_sql += " AND id_contattato = "+contact

            end

        end     



        if params[:state] 

            if params[:state][:id] != ""

                state = params[:state][:id]
              stringa_sql += " AND id_stato = "+state

            end

        end     



        if params[:manage] 

            if params[:manage][:id] != ""

                manage = params[:manage][:id]
              stringa_sql += " AND id_gestito = "+manage

            end

        end     


    if params[:consultation] 

        if params[:consultation][:id] != ""

            consultation = params[:consultation][:id]
          stringa_sql += " AND id_consulenza = "+consultation

        end

    end     



    if params[:formation] 

        if params[:formation][:id] != ""

            formation = params[:formation][:id]
            #formazione DA METTERE

        end

    end     



    if params[:software] 

        if params[:software][:id] != ""

            software = params[:software][:id]
            stringa_sql += " AND id_software = "+software

        end

    end     



    @companies = Company.search(stringa_sql).to_a

    if not @companies.empty? 
        redirect_to companies_index_path

    end
end
```

index:

```
  def index

    @companies ||= Company.all

  end
```

Comment: Assuming you are building the search query on `search` page, it should **post to `index`**, not back to `search` controller. In `index` you should check for params and either show everything, or filtered results. And, yes, `to_a` is fine.

Comment: i check the text-field in the search controller. Cause i want to show in the index page the list of the results. I execute the query in search controller and then i want to pass this result to index controller.Sorry , I don't understand you.

Comment: In frontend you have a search-box, presumably in a form, that _posts_ search result somewhere. Just post user input _directly to index controller_, not back to _search_.

Comment: is this the problem of the loop? can you explain me better what happens? thank you for the help

Comment: I can not explain you anything, besides my suggestions on what you are trying to achieve, until you have your frontend code posted.

Comment: **frontend code** is the code, that is executed in browser and posts entered by user search string to controller. I believe it posts to `search` controller, what is wrong. It should post to `index` controller. I am unable to explain that clearer.

Comment: i understand your advice. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used  @companies ||= Company.all cause i think that the  @companies
>   is and istance variable and it should be available in all the actions
>   of the class. Isn't it?

Not really, it depends on from where you want to access the `@companies` instance variable. e.g. from which view, you need `@companies` instance variable in the corresponding action method of the controller.

> The second time i call the search action it brings me into the index
>   action

You are using `redirect_to companies_index_path` in your `search` method which brings you to the index action.

**To implement search in your application**, you can follow this somewhat standard process:

In your `application_controller.rb` which will have the `@search_query`.

```
  # Returns string
  def search_query
    @search_query ||= params[:query] || params[:search]
  end
```

Then, in your `searches_controller.rb`, you can have:

```
  def search
    # in the method build your search results based on 
    # search_query param
    @search_results = Company.joins(:references).where(sql_string(search_query)).to_a
  end
```

In your `routes.rb`, you can have:

```
get '/search(/:query)' => 'searches#search', query: /.+/, as: 'search'
```

Which will take you to the searches_controller's `search` action where you are building the search results `@search_results`.

Finally, you need to have a `app/views/searches/search.html.erb` view file where you have access to your `@search_results` instance variable and you can just loop through them and display them in this view.

**Answers to your last 3 questions:**

> 1. passing @companies searching result to index action.
> 2. avoid the loop between search-index. So in every new request resets
>      the old searching.

You can overcome these problems by following the request/response flow that I have mentioned above. You should not share your `index` view with your `search` and you should not have any loop between `search` and `index`. Both of them are separate actions of the controller and can be handled separately as I showed above.

> 3. i want to know if it's correct the casting with the to_a to bring an
>      ActiveRecord:Relation to Array.

You can do that if you want. But, you don't really need it in this use case. You can store the `ActiveRecord:Relation` in your `search_results` and when you access this instance variable from inside your `search.html.erb` view, you can easily loop through using a `.each do` block. So, you don't have to worry about `ActiveRecord:Relation` and `Array`.